# Connect to SQL Server and Nmbrs in one session

Tags: sql-server, invantive-sql, nmbrs

I would like to insert data into SQL Server directly from NMBRS in a distributed transaction, like for instance:

```
insert into table@sqlserver
( fields )
select fields from employees@nmbrs
```

By default only the `datadictionary`, `inmemorystorage`, `os` and `mail` aliases are defined. How can I add the right aliases?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration in your `settings.xml` or `settings-<SOMETHING>.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<settings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3" forcedefault="false">
  <group name="Production" >
    <connection name="Stuff" >
      <database order="30" alias="nmbrs" provider="NmbrsNl" connectionString="apiurl=https://api.nmbrs.nl/soap/v2.1" />
      <database order="20" alias="sqlserver" provider="SqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=blabla;UID=stuff;PWD=secret" AllowConnectionStringRewrite="false" />
    </connection>
  </group>
</settings>
```

Put them in your `%USERPROFILE%\invantive folder`. A `settings-*.xml` will be merged with your central `settings.xml` file.

The disable on allow connection string rewrite makes it possible to hard-code the user name/password for SQL Server. When you remove it, the log on will ask you for the credentials of SQL Server too.